# GpyTorch: non differing confidence intervall

Tags: confidence-interval, gaussian-process, gpytorch

I'm using GpyTorch to model gaussian processes.
Since I'm new to this tool I adapted the doc tutorial in just a few ways to fit my training data.

Unfortunetly my confidence region is for every region of my x-axis the same height. Meaning that even on regions of my x-axis with a lot of uncertainty (for example around 0.25, (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvBwU.png)), the confidence region is not bigger than in areas with lower uncertainty. The model might has diffrent issues, but I managed to fix most of them.

I tried to get a diffrent confidence regions with multiple combinations from diffrent models and kernels and likelihoods, but none of them worked reliably.

`In the screenshot case I used:`

`gpytorch.models.ExactGP`

`gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()`

`gpytorch.kernels.AdditiveKernel(gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel(eps = 10))`

`gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal()`

`gpytorch.likelihoods.GaussianLikelihood()`

gpytorch.mlls.ExactMarginalLogLikelihood(likelihood, model)

Any idea how I can bring diffrent confidence regions into the model? Since there are diffrent combinations of model, kernel, likelihood and so on, which parameters have an impact on the confidence interval?

Already a big THANKS!